# Different token lifetime for email confirmation and reset password

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-identity

Is there any implementation of IUserTokenProvider where i can set different token lifetime for email confirmation token and reset password token? In identit 1.0 I could have two token providers (one for each purpose) right now there is only one.

There is DataProtectionTokenProvider but I can't set different lifetime.

Do I have to write my own TokenProvider or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported in Identity 2.0 version. They plan to introduce it in 3.0 https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/133

Right now you have to write your own token provider.